# Working with files with anchors, which options are there for Java?

Tags: java, html, file-io

I am working with files (reading, writing and copying) in my Java application, [java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html?is-external=true) and [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) were perfect for this kind of tasks.

Right now, I can link to HTML in this way:

```
Z:\an absolute\path\to\a\file.html
```

But, I need to provide support for anchors too:

```
Z:\an absolute\path\to\a\file.html#anchor
```

keeping the system-independence obtained by using java.io.File. So, I will need to extract the path and the anchor, I wonder whether it will be as easy as searching for a sharp occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`java.io.File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.net.URI%29) includes a constructor that accepts a [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), which can represent all kinds of resources, included URLs and local files (see the [rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)). URI's also meets your requirements of supporting anchors, and extracting path information (through `instance.getPath()`).

Comment: When trying to convert from java.io.File to java.net.URI using java.io.File.toURI() method the sharp (#) character is escaped. The final users don't care about URIs, they care about using their always-known-windows paths. In my case this won't be the solution, unless there is a more straighforward way to manage this issue.

Comment: I may have been unclear. I'm suggesting that you refactor your code to use URI's for all resources and to convert them as necessary, depending on what you need to do. This way the users can deal with local paths, or URL's, you just need to create the appropriate object for performing io. If your code doesn't make it simple to do that, then I see your dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File("Z:\\path\\to\\a\\file.html#anchor");
String anchor = f.toURL().getRef(); //note: toURL is deprecated
```

If you look at the java source you will see that it is as simple as:

```
String file = "Z:\\path\\to\\a\\file.html#anchor";
int ind = file.indexOf('#');
String anchor = ind < 0 ? null: file.substring(ind + 1);
```

Comment: This implies refactoring the whole code and taking care of not been able to use common java.io.File methods.